# how to deal with browser console error message of RESTful api request

Tags: javascript

When I code with restful API style, there are some non 200 Http Status Code what I set in response, and web browser show some error message in console, DO I need to deal with this problem? How can I hide those error messages?

The server use Spring-Boot and frontend developed using Vue.js, I think it has no relation with the programming language or web browser.

```
axios.get(URL).then(res => {
  this.result = true;
  if (res.data.code === 200) {
    this.userInfo = res.data.data
  } else {
    alert(res.data.msg)
  }
})
```

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8009/proxyApi/auth/v1/login 400 (Bad Request)
```

notice: this is not request loss params, the response body is "wrong account or password", I set Http status Code Because I use RESTful API style, and I'm wondering if it's necessary to deal with console error output?

Comment: you can call `console.clear()` after those errors appear? Is it what you want? Hide the error messages?

Comment: add the catch block `axios.get(URL).then(...).catch(console.log)`

Comment: 各位老哥懂中文的尽量讲中文好吗，我英语超差的/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~